# Display result of Pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi i have an slight problem i'm trying top geht tow Results of My pdo query and Print Them but No such luck i've probably just Made a Stupid mistake i'm Not seeing The query seems to be finde so it does make a difference if the name is in the database (and it makes a difference if you put it in quotes) probably the variables are getting a null value or something...

```
$username="xxx";
$firstname="xxx";
$check=0;
    if (isset($_GET['u'])){
        $username=strip_tags(@$_GET['u']);
        if (ctype_alnum($username)){
            $check=$stmt=$link->prepare("SELECT * FROM
users WHERE username = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($username));
            $check=$stmt->fetchAll();
            if(count($check)==1){
                $get=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
                echo "$get";
                $username =$get["username"];
                $firstname = $get["first_name"];
            }else{
                echo "<h2> User does not exist!</h2>";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>
<h2>Profilepage for: <?php echo "$username"; ?></h2>
<h2>First name: <?php echo "$firstname"; ?></h2
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: field username is unique?

Comment: Yep usename is unique but I'm just doing this to gain some experience and that most the data should be encrypted is clear to me I just wanted to alternate a bit between different methods and really see how my stuff works but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt->fetchAll()` is fetching all the results of the query. Once this is done, there are no more results available for `$stmt->fetch()` to fetch. You should get the data from the `$check` array.

```
if (count($check) == 1) {
    $get = $check[0];
    $username = $get["username"];
    $firstname = $get["first_name"];
} else {
    echo "<h2> Username does not exist </h2>";
    exit();
}
```

Or you could just replace the `fetchAll` with `fetch`.

```
$stmt->execute(array($username));
$get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($get) {
    $username = $get["username"];
    $firstname = $get["first_name"];
} else {
    echo "<h2> Username does not exist </h2>";
    exit();
}
```

Also, `echo "$get"` makes no sense. `$get` is an array, you can't echo it, you need to use `print_r($get)` or `var_dump($get)`.